# Theme a node form

Tags: nodes, forms, theming, 8

I'm attempting to theme a node add form for my new slide show content type in D8 using an example for D7 that I found [here](https://drupal.org/node/1200216), but I'm not having much luck.

I've made and enabled a module named modulename, and have this in modulename.module:

```
function modulename_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'slide_show_node_form' => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
      'template' => 'slide-show-node-form'
    ),
  );
}
```

and in `modulename/templates/slide-show-node-form.html.twig` I have this:

```
test
<div class="layout-node-form clearfix">
  <div class="layout-region layout-region-node-main">
    {{ form|without('advanced', 'actions') }}
  </div>
  <div class="layout-region layout-region-node-secondary">
    {{ form.advanced }}
  </div>
  <div class="layout-region layout-region-node-footer">
    {{ form.actions }}
  </div>
</div>
```

But, no luck on getting `test` to print out on the node add page. Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_node_form_alter(array &$form, array &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#theme'] = 'slide_show_node_form';
}
```

Comment: Using `jshow_forms_form_slide_show_node_form_alter` I was able to get `dpm` to output something, but using `$form['#theme'] = 'slide_show_node_form';` within it yielded no results.

Comment: Try hook_form_alter() instead. Sometimes even I don't pick proper form id so I always use this to be sure I get it right and then use the proper form id in the hook_form_FORM_ID_alter for better DX instead of having just one hook_form_alter.

Comment: I actually pulled the form_id from `hook_form_alter` (`dpm($form_id)` on the node create page) and double checked that `dpm()` was working on the node create page after I switched to `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter`, but it still didn't seem to be picking up my theme.

Comment: It may be stupid but just ot be sure, check if you are referencing the $form array in the function/hook arguments.

Comment: And of course always clear the cache :)

Comment: I used the exact format you used in your answer, only with `mymodule_form_slide_show_node_form_alter` instead of `mymodule_form_node_form_alter`.

Comment: Can you paste the .module code on pastebin or somewhere?

Comment: This function is literally the only thing in the module file, but: http://pastebin.com/0xV11N26

Comment: Well where's the hook_theme then?

Comment: It was replaced with what's there now.

Comment: But Drupal then won't know the theme funcion so no wonder nothing is happening.

Comment: Added `hook_theme` back and still no result. http://pastebin.com/ELjeLk8K

Comment: have you cleared the cache? Do you have the template file in /modules/mymodulename/templates/slide-show-node-form.html.twig ?

Comment: Cleared the cache via `drush cr` and the template is in `modules/mymodulename/templates/slide-show-node-form.html.twig`

Comment: just a wild giess but maybe try to rename the template(and the theme function) since it may be colliding with the node form/theme/template in some way.

Comment: I changed all of the `slide_show_node_form` (aside from the hook_form_FORM_ID_alter) to `slide_show_create` and still nothing.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding something like the following to the top of your `modulename/templates/slide-show-node-form.html.twig`

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Override for Slide Show Node Form 'form' element.
 *
 * Available variables
 * - attributes: A list of HTML attributes for the wrapper element.
 * - children: The child elements of the form.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_form()
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
#}
```

(based on the default located at `/core/modules/system/templates/form.html.twig`) and the suggestions for [Drupal Twig conversion instructions](https://drupal.org/node/2025313)